# Ajax Load More fade effect

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a fade effect on a load more function.

```
.done(function(response) {
   $('.content').append(response).hide().prependTo(".content").fadeIn("slow");
   offset += limit;
});
```

I'm loading my posts in content div. The first time when I click Load More it makes the fadeIn effect. When I press second time it makes the effect but to the whole .content.
My question is how to divide every load more content ?

```
<div class='content'>
  <div class='first-load'>
    // with fade in effect
  </div>
  <div class='second-load'>
    // only this div with fade in effect not the whole .content
  </div>
  ... etc
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is a little strange: your appending content into `.content`, and then you are nesting the entire element by prepending it to another `.content`... are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is kinda of weird. I think what you *actually* want is just this:

```
.done(function(response) {
   $(response).appendTo(".content").hide().fadeIn("slow");
   offset += limit;
});
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/0r0uv6rw/